# django strange behavior in include

Tags: django

I have create a very simple django project (python 2.7) with those commands:

```
django-admin.py startproject projet7
cd projet7
django-admin.py startapp app7
mkdir -p app7/api/rest
touch app7/api/__init__.py
touch app7/api/rest/__init__.py
```

I have created app7/api/rest/urls_api.py:

```
from django.conf import urls
urlpatterns = []

def register(view):
    p = urls.url(view.url_regex, view.as_view())
    urlpatterns.append(p)
    return view
```

and i have add this in projet7/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from app7.api.rest import urls_api
...
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^api/', include(urls_api)),
]
```

It works ! Great

But if i add this instead, in projet7/urls.py:

```
   from django.conf.urls import include
   from app7.api import rest
   ...
    urlpatterns = [
        ...
        url(r'^api/', include(rest.urls_api)),
    ]
```

It does not work. I get this error. I do not understand why. It should be the same ?

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urls_api'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's just not the same.

When you do `from app7.api import rest`, you practically import `app7/api/rest/__init__.py`.

(`os.path` might be where you know this import style from, and it has [special magic](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/os.py#L91) to make all that happen.)

I'd simply suggest importing the most specific module, or if you're absolutely sure you don't want to do that, do `import .urls_api as urls_api` in `rest/__init__.py` (but beware of any eventually possible circular import concerns).